# how to check if file exist based on file partial name

Tags: linux, bash, files, wildcards

the way to check file as all know is like this

```
[[ -f  /var/scripts_home/orig_create_DB_files_1.46.38 ]] && echo file exist
```

but how to check if file exist in case file contain name as - "**create_DB_files**"

I try this ( but not works )

```
[[ -f  /var/scripts_home/*create_DB_files* ]] && echo file exist
```

or

```
   partial_file_name=create_DB_files

   [[ -f  /var/scripts_home/*$partial_file_name* ]] && echo file exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for name in *create_DB_files*; do
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
        printf 'at least one file exists (%s)\n' "$name"
        break
    fi
done
```

That is, match the relevant names and check if any of them is a regular file (the loop will exit as soon as one is found).

Answer (score 2):

This will test whether a file exists based on a partial name with all the flexibility for finding files that `find` allows:

```
find . -name '*create_DB_files*' -printf 1 -quit | grep -q 1
```

One might want to consider adding `-type f` to restrict matches to regular files or `-mtime` if one wants to match on file date, or `-maxdepth 1` to restrict the search to the current directory, etc.

The above can be incorporated in an `if` command as follows:

```
if find . -name '*create_DB_files*' -printf 1 -quit | grep -q 1
then
    echo found
else
    echo Not found
fi
```

Comment: Add `-type f` to not get positive results from directories etc.

Comment: Yes, @Kusalananda, that is a good point & it is already mentioned in the answer.